# How do I define a method in Ruby to have the same function of escapeHTML?

Tags: ruby, erb

I want code that uses a method named "h" to have the same output this code in ERB does:

```
<code>
  <%= CGI::escapeHTML(the_string) %>
</code>
```

Output of above code:

```
<!doctype html> <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Black Cat</title></head> <img 
src=blackcat.gif /> <script type="text/javascript">alert('If you see this, your\'re 
vulernable to XSS!');</script>
```

Output of above code in website form for clarification: http://hills.ccsf.edu/~wly3/cs132a/lab4.cgi

Two questions:

1) How should I modify this code to incorporate escapeHTML and to remove unnecessary code? (I'm not sure which requires/includes I need)

```
module CgiHelper

require 'cgi'
require "erb"
include ERB::Util

  def h
    #code
  end
```

2) How should I modify the ERB in the beginning so that it works with the "h" method?

Any help is appreciated. Trial and error hasn't returned results for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create the `h` helper method

```
module CgiHelper
  require "erb"
  include ERB::Util

  def h(s)
    html_escape(s)
  end
end
```

2) Use the `h` helper method

```
<code>
  <%= h(the_string) %>
</code>
```